# Error loading WSDL from resource when running in AWS Lambda

Tags: java-8, aws-lambda, wsdl

I imported a WSDL file and modified my service to read from the project's resource.

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "MyService", targetNamespace = "http://www.myservice.com/MyService", wsdlLocation = "/documentation/wsdl/MyService.wsdl")
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final static URL MYSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException MYSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName MYSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://www.myservice.com/MyService", "MyService");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = URL.class.getResource("/documentation/wsdl/MyService.wsdl");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        MYSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        MYSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }
  ...
}
```

Running locally, it works perfectly. Running on an AWS Lambda, the following error occurs:

```
FATAL Failed to access the WSDL at: file:/documentation/wsdl/MyService.wsdl. It failed with: 
    /documentation/wsdl/MyService.wsdl (No such file or directory).
> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: file:/documentation/wsdl/MyService.wsdl. It failed with: 
    /documentation/wsdl/MyService.wsdl (No such file or directory).
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:250)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing "wsdllocation" property from @WebServiceClient and changing load resource method solve the problem:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "MyService", targetNamespace = "http://www.myservice.com/MyService")
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final static URL MYSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException MYSERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName MYSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://www.myservice.com/MyService", "MyService");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("documentation/wsdl/MyService.wsdl");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        MYSERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        MYSERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }
  ...
}
```